# Why are Vue dynamic components destroyed inside loop every re-render?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I run into an issue with Vuejs 2.x version (latest). While rendering a list of item inside a loop, if I make changes to the items then the normal components are not destroyed but the dynamic components will always be destroyed:

I have put a short sample code here:
https://gist.github.com/yellow1912/fc1c053e07c1ca136148484cf7f79d1a

I have also put a codepen here:
https://codepen.io/raineng/pen/zYGOXYY?editors=1111

```
<nl-test inline-template>
    <div>
        <div v-on:click="increase"> increase here please </div><br><br>
        <div v-on:click="decrease"> decrease here please </div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(value, key) in getItems()" :key="key">
                printing
                <component :is="getItem()" :key="key"></component>
                <nl-test inline-template>
                    <div>
                        this is a test here
                    </div>
                </nl-test>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nl-test>
```

To see what I mean, open the console tab on codepen, click the add item and you will see that the dynamic component items are destroyed and re-created everytime.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why, I need to use keep-alive:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

To quote:

> When switching between these components though, you’ll sometimes want
> to maintain their state or avoid re-rendering for performance reasons
>
> Recreating dynamic components is normally useful behavior, but in this
> case, we’d really like those tab component instances to be cached once
> they’re created for the first time. To solve this problem, we can wrap
> our dynamic component with a  element

Wasted 2 days on this issue and then I found the answer just a moment after posting this on StackOverflow. Hope it helps someone.